# Chats are no longer RCS after restore

Tags: sms, data-recovery, google-messages, rich-communication-services

I have Android 14 with root. I restored my text messages from a backup made with Swift Backup. Now no conversations are using RCS, even the ones that did before the restore. For example it's now showing the received and red check marks. RCS is already turned on in settings. I tried toggling it but it didn't help. I'm using the stock SMS app. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Restoring RCS messages is hacky as there aren't real APls in Android to deal with them](https://t.me/swiftbackupsupport/79763) from Swift Backup Telegram ss stated but developer

Answer (score -1):

Actually, this may be [Google's doing:](https://www.theverge.com/2024/3/1/24087418/google-messages-blocking-rcs-on-rooted-android-devices)

> Google is cracking down on rooted Android devices, blocking multiple people from using the RCS message feature in Google Messages. Users with rooted phones — a process that unlocks privileged access to the Android operating system, like jailbreaking iPhones — have made several reports on the Google Messages support page, Reddit, and XDA’s web forum over the last few months, finding they’re suddenly unable to send or receive RCS messages.
>
> One example from Reddit user u/joefuf shows that RCS messages would simply vanish after hitting the send button. Several reports also mention that Google Messages gave no indication that RCS chat was no longer working, and was still showing as connected and working in Google Messages.

Comment: Looks like the question is about restoring text messages as RCS, not about being unable to use RCS after rooting.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought at first but then the description explains that conversations are not RCS. Maybe the OP didn't test sending and receiving new messages.

I also wonder if anything can restore the messages to a new phone as RCS rather than them converting to SMS/MMS.